# How to make install .Net 4.5.2 automatically when setup.exe starts in installscript msi project

Tags: .net, installshield, installscript

First, I'm using Installshield Premier 2012.

My application uses minimum .Net Framework 4.5.2 and I want to make installshield setup.exe downloads .Net Framework 4.5.2 too.

I've tried .Net Framework 4.5 Full(Extract From Setup.exe option and same Installation requirements) and it worked well as I expected.

But there were not 4.5.2 requirements check in default option, I downloaded DOTNETVERSION452FULL.ini from other website.

After it, I changed requirement to Net Framework 4.5.2 and Extract Net Framework 4.5.2 from setup.exe too.

But it shows only Installer Information dialog 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Full package or greater needs to be installed for this installation to continue.' and install fail.

What do I have to do?

[error dialog image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHxAn.png)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find it and installed with other way.

My solution was

[img01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3STHr.png)

adding another feature only for .NET Framework.

If user select .NET Framework in custom installation, installer extracts .NET Framework into INSTALLDIR.

Finally, .NET Framework installation starts when user clicks 'Finish' button.

And I wanted to add two installation, I added two different launchappandwait codes in installscript.

```
function OnEnd()
STRING szProgram, szCmdLine;
```

begin

```
szProgram = INSTALLDIR ^ "FirstSetup.exe";
szCmdLine = "";
//First install
if(LaunchAppAndWait(szProgram, szCmdLine, WAIT) < 0) then
endif;

szProgram = INSTALLDIR ^ "NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe";//Last Installation must be .NET Framework. Because .NET Framework doesn't allow other installation programs.
//NET Framework install
if(LaunchAppAndWait(szProgram, szCmdLine, NOWAIT) < 0) then//NOWAIT Makes exit current installation when user clicks finish
endif;
```

end;

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But did you check redistributables section and trying edit the .prq file over there for different condition?